# How can I insert data to my database automatically based on count down timer in laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.8, countdowntimer

To elaborate,I am working on a game app where the business logic is that, every game is for 3 minutes( we have a timer which runs backwards). I need to add the id, gamecode and status to the Game table(Data has to be added automatically)
Next once 3 minutes are done,(i.e,Timer reaches 0.00sec) second game starts,second game details have to be inserted, and the cycle goes on. So I have to use scheduler for this?. Would be a super help if someone can guide me on the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use ajax and setInterval or setTimeout. You would need jquery for ajax.

Comment: Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & always try to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)